# How to parse json in Vue js to use it in template

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

```
<template>
    <div class="row w-20 " >
        <div class="card col-4 ">
             <ul>
                <li v-for="message in conversations.messages" :key="message.messages">
                    {{message.text}}  
                </li>        
            </ul> 
            
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    
    props: ['conversation_index_route'],
    data() {
        return {
            conversations: [],
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/comms/conversation/',
            
        }
    },
    beforeMount() {
        this.$eventBus.$on('selectConversation', this.getConversations)
        this.getConversations();
    },
    methods: {
        getConversations(id) {
            console.log(this.url+id);
            axios.get(this.url+ id)
                .then(response => {
                    this.conversations = response.data;
                    this.conversations = JSON.parse(this.conversations.message);
                    console.log(this.conversations);

                });            
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

```
conversation_index_route:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/comms/conversation"
conversations:Object
all_staff_attended:false
centre_id:5
children:""
classes:""
cover_image:"https://via.placeholder.com/150x150"
created_at:"2020-05-30 19:01:59"
exited_users:null
id:257
last_id:null
messages:Array[1]
  0:"{"_id":1854,"text":"This is the beginning of this conversation","createdAt":"2020-05-30 19:01:59","system":true}"
parent_users:"3016"
parents:Array[1]
staff_users:"180,181"
staffs:Array[2]
status_id:1
title:"Test"
updated_at:"2020-05-30 19:01:59"
url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/comms/conversation/"
```

[image: This is the data I got and want to parse the message array]

So what shall I code to use the message text in my template to display the text messages?

Comment: Just Try   {{message[0].text}} . Its work because text is inside Message Array. @Archaana

Answer (score 9):

You'd have to do `JSON.parse(conversations.messages[0]).text`. This way you parse the object inside `messages` and have access to its properties.

Comment: heyyy hiiii , this is wat he ask me to do .. but can i know where to code this line exactly .. there is where i am stucked.. soorryy to ask that

Comment: heyy thanks man , i got it already ... i {{JSON.parse(conversations.messages).text}} inside the v-for

Comment: `JSON.parse(sub_categories)` works well thank you

Answer (score 1):

Simply JSON.parse the string

```
var myJson = "[{\"id\":72,\"food_item_id\":\"56\",\"variation_id\":\"20\",\"price\":\"50\",\"created_at\":\"2021-06-29T05:29:14.000000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2021-06-29T05:29:14.000000Z\",\"variant\":null}]";
var myJson2 = JSON.parse(myJson);
console.log(myJson2);
```